# How to access elements of a dynamic vector?

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, vector, malloc

I want to move from a matrix to a dynamic vector through a function. Then to verify that everything goes well, I want to print the vector elements.

Function:

```
    float **v;
    float ** matrix_to_vector(const float m[][2],size_t n){
    v = (float **)malloc(n * sizeof(float*));
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        v[i] = (float *)malloc(n * sizeof(float)); 
    for(j=0;j<MAX_COLS;j++){
        *(v[i]) = m[i][j];
    }
}
return v;
}

On main():
float ** vector;
vector = matriz_a_vector(m,cantidad);

for(i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
    for(j=0;j<MAX_COLS;j++){
        printf("%f\t",*(vector[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

My problem is that I always keep the M [ I][ 1]element, since when the cycle is completed, it always holds value in v [ I]. When i print the vector only prints me the values of M [ I] [ 1] because it is the ones that keep the variable. How can I get to access all the elements and get them all printed out?

Comment: You probably want to do `vector[i][j]` or `vector[j][i]` in printing and the same in the copying part, but note your code has some other issues also. You allocate space for n*n floats, then copy n*MAX_COLS while telling the function your data is n*2 items. This only works if n is 2, otherwise there will be issues.

Comment: That's because in this problem they tell me I have a n - ranking matrix and 2 columns. It's fixed, it s a particular problem.
I still have a problem, my problem is: *(v[i]) = m[i][j]; That gives me access to all the vector elements created. I am thinking this way, that from v I can enter all the vector elements in R ^ 2. And when printing I always have element v [0] [i].
Perhaps, i should change the logic of how to enter the vector elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Once memory was requested for v [i] in the first for, then it copied the Matrix values in the vector created. Then I did a function to print that Vector apart.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<MAX_COLS;j++){
            v[i][j] = m[i][j];  
        }
    }
```